# Parse json and give to category in Highcharts

Tags: json, highcharts

I am using Highcharts and want to parse JSON and assign to categories part.

This is my chart data:

```
var chartData = { 
  "chart" :[
    {name: "kolkata",categories: ["male", "female"]},
    {name: "Mumbai",categories: ["male", "female"]}
  ]
}
```

I tried this:

```
var category = [];
var Count = chartData.chart;
for (var i=0; i< Count.length; i++) {
  category.push({name : chartData.chart[i].name, categories : chartData.chart[i].categories})
}
```

Finally:

```
xAxis: {                    
  categories: category
}
```

The category not coming properly on x axis. Does anybody have an idea why it's not?

Comment: How do you call your highchart? using jquery?

Comment: Hi, I thing that you can use your code and it will display your chart correctly. Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/L37b4t26/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you need to include library

include following library

```
<script src="http://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/grouped-categories.js"></script>
```